# Scrollable DIV in TD works in WebKit, but not in Gecko

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I'm working on a school project, and I have to create a simple presentation webpage. The problem is that the webpage doesn't work as expected in Firefox, while in Chrome and othet WebKit browser it's all fine.

My problem is here: http://c303.usv.ro/~HPC/ (please don't change the language in English, as you will not be able to see my problem). If you go to "Echipamente" in Chrome, you'll see that the "#content" div has some nice scrollbarls and the footer stays at the bottom. If you'll do that in Firefox, the scrollbars no longer appears and the footer seems to go somewhere under the visible part of the webpage. As a workaround I use:

```
function mozillaFix(){  
    return; // we shouldn't use this
    $('#content').height($('#maindiv').height() - $('#topheader').height() - $('#copynote').height() - 40)
    $('#leftmenu').height($('#maindiv').height() - $('#topheader').height() - $('#copynote').height() - 40)
}
```

but I guess that this is not the mos elegant solution. Where could be the issue?

Comment: Offtopic comment: You really like text shadow! Works well though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `max-height` with Javascript to the desired height (I tested it with FireBug to with `max-height: 400px;`). Then, Firefox will make a nice scrollbar, and show the footer as you wanted.

---

As found on the internet, the solution is defining the height of the container of the div. If you have the following CSS it should work:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: that's just a work around.. not the solution.. can u tell why its working in chrome and not in FF?

Comment: I don't know if the OP edited the css file a moment ago, but to me it seems the problem is solved. I think the `html, body {height: 100%}` did the trick...

Comment: I didn't edited the CSS, I just used the JS workaround in the original post. Yes, a little hacky but... doesn't matter, it works

I was already using that CSS code, but with no effect.